# How to split rows in a huge data file based on number of column within them in linux ?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have data file looks like:

```
1
2 4 5 6 7 19
20
22
24 26 27 
29 30 31 32 34 40 50 56 58
234 235 270 500
1234 1235 1236 1237
2300
```

I want to split those rows with more than 4 column to smaller rows with maximum 4 columns within each row. therefore the  output should be:

```
 1
 2 4 5 6 
 7 19
 20
 22
 24 26 27 
 29 30 31 32
 34 40 50 56
 58
 234 235 270 500
 1234 1235 1236 1237
 2300
```

Any suggestion please? Please consider that my real data file is huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ if(NF>4) for(i=5; i<=NF; i+=4) $i = "\n" $i } 1' file
```

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/ /\n/4;T;P;D' file
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -lpe '$c = 0; s/ /++$c % 4 ? " " : "\n"/goe' file
```

Output:

```
1
2 4 5 6 
7 19
20
22
24 26 27 
29 30 31 32 
34 40 50 56 
58
234 235 270 500
1234 1235 1236 1237
2300
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be a late merge or zipper method. Assume last character of each line is white space. First split your file into two, with respect to the columns you want to cut.

```
cut -d' ' -f1-4 file > file1
cut -d' ' -f5- file > file2
```

Secondly merge the files via late merge and delete empty lines.

```
paste -d'\n' file1 file2 | sed '/^$/d'
```